# Set logo in facebook login confirmation

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I'm new to Facebook API login. I want to add my logo in the login confirmation page of user. In the below image, the red boxed image has to be my logo.

[image]

How to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Go to your facebook App in developer.facebook.com.com
than in `App Detail` select the `Icons`
you can eaisily set your logo hear